# SQL Setting a Date Using variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have the following T-SQL

```
declare @earliest_date date;
begin
    if month(getdate()) < 7
    begin
        set @earliest_date = cast(cast(year(getdate()) -1 as varchar) + '07-01' as date)
    END
    ELSE
    begin
        set @earliest_date =  cast(cast(year(getdate()) as varchar) + '07-01' as date)
    end
end
select @earliest_date
```

I get the following error message:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Why do I keep getting this error message?

**Edit #1**

Here is what I am trying to do:

I am trying to set a date variable. If the month of today's date is < 7, I want the year to be set as last year, otherwise, set as this year.

So for Jan - June, the year would be 2020, otherwise, 2021, using this year as an example.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: `202107-01` is not a regular datetime pattern...

Comment: That is what solved the problem. dammit...I should have looked closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @earliest_date date;
begin
  if month(getdate()) < 7
  begin
    set @earliest_date = cast(cast(year(getdate()) -1 as varchar(4)) + '-07-01' as date)
  END
  ELSE
  begin
    set @earliest_date =  cast(cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) + '-07-01' as date)
  end
 end
 select @earliest_date
```

and if you want to use your way then please see above

Answer (score 1):

If you want July 1st last year, use:

```
datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 1, 7, 1)
```

If you want July 1st this year, use:

```
datefromparts(year(getdate()), 7, 1)
```

If you want the most recent July first, subtract six months from the date:

```
datefromparts(year(dateadd(-6, month, getdate())), 7, 1)
```

You can save these into a variable.  Or just use them in a query.